# Тире в предложении c "не"

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Нужно ли тире в предложении: «Экономия ради экономии» – не лучший принцип жизни.

Answer (score 1):

*Экономия ради экономии – не лучший принцип жизни.*

Здесь необходима пауза для определения состава распространенного подлежащего, поэтому ставится тире даже при наличии частицы НЕ.

А вот кавычки мне кажутся лишними, так как высказывание в первой части не является цитатой.

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Тире не ставится:

3) если перед сказуемым стоит отрицание не: Офицер этот не чета вам (Фед.); …Уссурийский тигр совсем не сказка, явь почти (Март.); Бедность не порок (Погов.); Сердце не камень (Погов.); Аналогия не доказательство.
**Постановка тире в этом случае имеет целью логически и интонационно подчеркнуть сказуемое**: Но объяснение — не оправдание (М. Г.); Его взгляды на семейный этикет — не предрассудок ли это?;

Comment: К сожалению, те, кто задает вопросы, редко бывают щедры на контекст. А без контекста нельзя категорически утверждать, что высказывание в первой части не является цитатой.

Comment: Если даже у этого высказывания был автор, то его, я думаю, никто его не помнит. Используется оно часто, например:http://www.oneoflady.com/2011/10/blog-post_1141.html